# How to add dropdownlist to next row after selection in mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have entity called "Object". **{ Id, Name, UpperObjectId}**

Items of dropdownlist are composed of name of those **objects**.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => objectlist[0].TempValue,
    new SelectList(objectlist, "Id", "Name"), 
    "Choose",
    new {@onchange = "javascript:GetItems(this.value);",
    name = "newlist",
    @class = "form-control"})
```

After select any item on list,I want to create new dropdownlist to next row if selected item have children objects.

The new dropdownlist shoul list items whose UpperObjectId equal to id of selected object of previous dropdownlist. (**objectlist.Where(o=>o.UpperObject ==selecteditem.Id)**)

```
function GetItems(objectId) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("CreateObjectItems", "Object")';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            objectId: objectId
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#NewdropDownList").html(data);
        },
    });
```

I try to it by using ajax. If there is children object then create new dropdown list and it works recursively until no children object left.

But I dont know How to design it in view?
How I can do it by using ajax or any other way?

You can see list of my objects on image.

[image: Here is sample objectlist]

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { nesneId: nesneId },
            //cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var div = document.getElementById('altliste');
                div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + data;
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });
```

- I have used partialview.
- In control, I check if there is sublist or not.
- if there is, it appends partialview html to next line then.